# No JDK found during WebStorm installation

Tags: jdk, ide

After extracting the *tar.gz*, and `$ cd ~/<directory>/WebStorm-141.1550/bin`
and after typing in the terminal `$ sudo ./webstorm.sh` as explained,
I get an ERROR massage:

> No JDK found. Please validate either WEBIDE_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME
>   environment variable points to valid JDK installation.

What is that JDK and what version should I choose?
([JetBrain support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827547-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under))

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JDK stands for **J**ava **D**evelopment **K**it :

> The Java Development Kit (JDK) is an implementation of either one of
>   the Java SE, Java EE or Java ME platforms released by Oracle
>   Corporation in the form of a binary product. The JDK includes a
>   private JVM and a few other resources to finish the recipe to a Java
>   Application.
>   Via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit)

---

I advise you to use the Java 8 JDK. You can get it by installing Java 8 on your computer :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Once installed relaunch WebStorm - it will work fine.

---

See on the [Ubuntu Java Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) for more informations.

Comment: I have no idea :O

Comment: @TzahiLeh did you managed to get it work ?

Comment: after the first line it says:
`Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.`

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`, reboot your computer and try again.

Comment: It works! :DDDD

Comment: I thought WebStorm is free, but on the installation it asks for a license key or a 30 days trial :O

Comment: Unfortunately no. You can get it free if you are student or working on an open-source project. See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/buy/) for more informations.

Comment: What about JDK 13? this is the latest as in Dec 2019. Tried to export the JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME as well as PAT but still didnt work.

Comment: and FYI that add-apt-repository no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest versions of Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-jre#2-installing-openjdk-jre

Answer (score 0):

The OpenJDK is available within Ubuntu repositories:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre`
3. `java -version` to check that installation is successful.

It is substantially more difficult and riskier to install 'Oracle' Java.
 There is some documentation on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) which does recommend the [WebUpd8 ppa](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java).

---

The information from the [Jetbrains site](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/system-requirements-and-installation.html#d196792e222) no longer works:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"`  (Replace lucid with your version of Ubuntu)
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin`
4. `java -version` to check that installation is successful.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid has reached end of life since 2013 and Java 8 is now out. I am afraid this documentation is outdated...

Comment: So it is.  I am using a number of JetBrains products  PyCharm / Webstorm / IntelliJ / RubyMin with the OpenJDK, and I thought it would be better post their official answer.